# Creating a Grails 'template' project for later reuse

Tags: grails

I'm building out a Grails app and realize that a lot of custom stuff would be useful in other projects I'll have on my palette and wonder what would be a prudent way to reuse that? 
Not just common functionality domain classes, controllers and corresponding gsp views, but services, tags, css files, etc.

From what I gather [Weceem CMS](http://www.weceem.org/weceem/) can run as a stand alone app or a plugin, would that approach be most practical? 
Ideally it would be great to be able to apply/update changes in 'template' project to ones dependent on it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's several ways to implement this. My approach would probably be to use the reusable controller or GSPs as a plugin. I would [create the plugin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) (which is almost identical to creating a regular grails application) then create a local package for it and finally whenever I need to use it, install the local plugin in another project. The thing is, plugins does not necessarily need to be coming from the grails repo, it can be from a local package like:

```
grails install-plugin c:\\my\\local\\path\\grails-example-0.1.zip
```

Comment: that's what I'm thinking too, but wonder about the static resources, JS, css, etc.

Comment: @vector you can include static resources in a plugin